# Is the action (a functional) a functional of both the Lagrangian (a function) and the trajectory (a function) or only the Lagrangian?

Tags: classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, variational-calculus

In Lagrangian Mechanics, would it be correct for me to say that the **action** (which is a functional) is a functional of two functions, namely the **Lagrangian** (a function) and the **trajectory** in configuration space (another function)?

Can I say that the action functional actually depends on two functions (Lagrangian and trajectory)? Or instead is it more correct to say that the action functional depends only on the Lagrangian, and the Lagrangian is a function which depends on the trajectory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I say that the action functional actually depends on two functions (Lagrangian and trajectory)?

I don't think so, Lagrangian is helper function that defines the action as functional on trajectories (for given system). When I dumbed it down,  it is kind of like $f=2*sin x$ is not a function of $sin$ and $x$, it is just function of $x$, where $sin$ is helper function which helps to define $f$. And I don't think you can take system as variable of action (how or why would you vary it?) , it is rather that every system has its own action associated with it.

Comment: So I could say that the action depends only on the Lagrangian, and the Lagrangian itself depends on the trajectory?

Comment: @polytheneman Lagrangian usually does not depend on the trajectory, only on the state of the system. In action you integrate this Lagrangian along the trajectory so the variable is path of the integration, not integrand.

Comment: @polytheneman As i said in my answer, you should distinguish dependence and definition. Action is defined by the Lagrangian and it depends on the trajectory. Lagrangian is defined by the physics and it depends on the state of the system. Of course if you change the definition of action by changing Lagrangian, action changes. But this is not dependence in mathematical sense, this is simply different quantity.